A Hölder bound on an integral involving the complex exponential.
I want to show that if $\gamma \in (0,1)$ we have:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{|e^{i x \cdot \xi}-e^{iy\cdot \xi}|^2}{|\xi|^{n+2\gamma}}\,\mathrm d \xi \le C_{n , \gamma} |x-y|^{2 \gamma}$$
for some $C_{n,\gamma}>0$ only dependent on $n, \gamma$.
Some ideas:
We can use the fact $f(z)=e^{iz}$ has complex derivative of modulus $\le 1$ and Cauchy-Schwarz to bound the numerator. Hölder/Cauchy Schwarz inequalities in the relevant $L^p$ spaces come to mind, as does splitting up the integral into a near $0$ and tail term and bounding contributions.
None of these seem to give bounds of the right form from what I have tried however.

Write the integrand as
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{|e^{i(x-y)\cdot \xi} - 1|^2}{|\xi|^{n + 2 \gamma}} \ \mathrm{d} \xi= \int_{|x-y||\xi| < 1} + \int_{|x-y||\xi| \ge 1}
\end{align*}
$$
We bound the first integral using $|e^{i(x-y)\cdot \xi} - 1| \le |\xi||x-y|$. Thus using polar coordinates,
$$
\int_{|x-y||\xi| < 1} \le \int_{|x-y||\xi| < 1} \frac{|x-y|^2}{|\xi|^{n + 2(\gamma - 1)}} \ \mathrm{d} \xi \le c_n|x-y|^2\int_0^{|x-y|^{-1}} r^{1-2\gamma}\  \mathrm{d} r \le c_{\gamma, n} |x-y|^{2\gamma}.
$$
The second integral is estimated using $|e^{i(x-y)\cdot \xi} - 1| \le 2$. Thus
$$
\int_{|x-y||\xi| \ge 1} \le \int_{|x-y||\xi| \ge 1}  \frac{4}{|\xi|^{n+2\gamma}} \ \mathrm{d} \xi\le c_n \int_{|x-y|^{-1}}^{\infty} r^{-1-2\gamma}\  \mathrm{d} r \le c_{\gamma, n}|x-y|^{2\gamma}
$$
